# Logic App with Managed Identity that gets triggered when a new Azure KeyVault Secret is to Expire

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity, azure-eventgrid

I have managed to create a Logic App that can send an email once an Azure KeyVault secret is about to expire. This works with my own credentials, but I cannot make it work with Managed Identity api connection.

For my Logic App I have enabled System Identity. Chosen "When an Event Grid resource event occurs" as the trigger and added RBAC role "Key Vault Administrator" to my Azure KeyVault

[image]

This now allows me to choose my KeyVault in the drop down menus on the trigger, which means my Managed Identity does have a connection to the KeyVault and I can pick up values in the drop down lists:

[image]

When I try to save this I get the following error:

*Failed to save logic app logic-secrets-expiry-poc-mi. The workflow connection parameter 'azureeventgrid' is not valid. The API connection 'azureeventgrid' is configured to support managed identity but the connection parameter is either missing 'authentication' property in connection properties or authentication type is not 'ManagedServiceIdentity'.*

What am I missing here?

**Update:** I found a workaround. I the Code view in the UI, I added this to the connection part:

```
"connectionProperties": {
        "authentication": {
             "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
                   }
         }
```

so that it looks now like this:

[image]

This allows me to Save the Logic App in the Portal without getting the error.

**Update:** However I cannot get it to trigger even when I add another Event to listen to like "Microsoft.KeyVault.SecretNewVersionCreated" and try to create new Secrets in KeyVault. It is not being triggered.

Comment: Have you tried using Standard logic app?

Comment: No, what would be different there? As I said I have made the whole thing work by using my own EntraID credentials when using the "When an Event Grid resource event occurs" trigger. It just works. But it is hard to find documentation on how to configure it with Managed Identity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to use Managed Identity from A-Z:

Start by creating a Key Vault and a Logic App (Consumption type used in this demo)
[image]

Enable Managed Identity on your Logic App:
[image]

Use RBAC permission model:
[image]

Add 2 RBAC roles to your KeyVault:

- Key Vault Crypto Service Encryption User
- Key Vault Secrets Office
  [image]

Verify that the RBAC roles have been added:
[image]
[image]

Add a trigger for your Logic App using Managed Identity:
[image]

and choose these events:
[image]

Verify that the Trigger History has no errors:
[image]

Check that that the Event Grid Subscription has been created:
[image]

Create a new Secret:
[image]

Check that your Logic App has been triggered now:
[image]

And in the final step you can see details in the run:
[image]

Done

Answer (score 2):

> It is not being triggered.

I have got triggered and below is my approach:

Firstly gave this role to managed identity of my logic app:

[image]

Then gave Key Vault Secrets Officer :

[image]

Need to have RBAC for Key Vault:

[image]

Then have used below **`design`**:

```
/subscriptions/<subscriptionid>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroupname>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<keyvaultname>
```

[image]

**`Output:`**

When version changed it got triggered.

[image]

Comment: This works. My missing link was the RBAC role "Key Vault Secrets Officer". And it has created an Event Grid Subscription under Events under KeyVault settings pane. I will test it out one more time from scratch in a new RG just to confirm A-Z approach. But thank you so much. This is really useful. For my Service Principal that accesses the Secrets in my KeyVault, I think I then also need to assign this RBAC role to and configure the KeyVault to use the RBAC control instead of usual Access Policies, right?

Comment: Yes, @OliverNilsen, Glad it Solved your issue

Comment: I am trying the same actions on my work subscription, and when saving the Logic App I can see the following error under Trigger History (Not Run History) "The client 'myLogicApp' with object id 'LogicAppEntraId' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/write' over scope '/subscriptions/xxx-xxx/resourceGroups/RG-KV-Logic-POC/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/kv-secrets-expiry-poc/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/LogicApp-xxx' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."

Comment: @OliverNilsen, If you follow my approach you will get output as i have got by doing the same.

Comment: I totally followed your approach 2 times. One in my own Azure Tenant where this totally works. I do the same thing in my work Azure Tenant and I can see the Logic App is saved just fine, however there are not Event Grid Subscriptions under the KeyVault Events pane and I get this error "'LogicAppEntraId' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/write". So it didn't create the Event Grid Subscription in my work Subscription somehow.

Comment: You need to add RBAC role "Key Vault Crypto Service Encryption User" to the KeyVault as well as this has the action "Key Vault Crypto Service Encryption User" which can create the Event Grid Subscription on the KeyVault. I will write an answer to my question with screenshots now.